# Build a Avro Schema with a list of field names and the same schema

Tags: java, java-stream, avro

im having a problem finding a solution for my problem.

I need to call the field method between the struct() and the build() method x times to create a new object. It's a builder pattern.

```
Schema people = SchemaBuilder.struct()
                .field("NAME", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
                .field("SURNAME", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
                .field("CITY", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
                .build();
```

But in my case, the fields of the people schema are not defined from the beginning. They need to be variable. I need something like:

```
String[] values = {"NAME", "SURNAME", "CITY", "FIELD4", "FIELD5", .....};

Schema people = SchemaBuilder.struct()
          .xTimes.field(values[x], Schema.STRING_SCHEMA))
          .build();
```

I looked at Streams and lambdas but never worked with them and am not sure if those could be a solution for this case. I can't interrupt the methods. They all need to be called in one row.
Is what I'm trying to do even possible and if yes, how?

Thanks

EDIT:
This is what I tried but didn't work:

```
public Schema buildSchema(String... fields){
  sch1 = SchemaBuilder.struct();
  for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    sch1 =SchemaBuilder.struct().field(fields[i], Schema.STRING_SCHEMA);
  }
  return sch1;
}
```

This works perfectly fine but doesn't fit my needs:

```
public Schema buildSchema(){
  Schema sch1 = SchemaBuilder.struct()
    .field("foo", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
    .field("bar", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
    .field("duck", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
    .build();
  return sch1
}
```

Comment: Have you worked with iterator? plain old loops?

Comment: Yes, but because it's a builder pattern it creates a new object every time I call the struct function. I can't  interrupt the builder with a loop. The fields need to be passed in one go.

Comment: Update your attempts in the question as you [edit it further](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60654116/edit) and not as comments.

Comment: Btw, you could enhance the given answer with a map of field names to schemas. It would make sense to have the SchemaBuilder class support a method that takes a map like that, but maybe it doesnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] values = {"NAME", "SURNAME", "CITY", "FIELD4", "FIELD5", .....};

SchemaBuilder builder = SchemaBuilder.struct();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    builder = builder.field(values[i], Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
}
Schema people = builder.build();
```

how bout something like that?

Comment: This did it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you. I used Stackoverflow the first time to ask a question. I'm completely new here. Btw, why does my question got two downvotes?

Comment: @at1ll3y I am not sure. question seems fine to me

Comment: @at1ll3y i was one of them, due to "lack of research". because i literally whipped up tihs "answer" in under two minutes. No disrespect meant, but you didn't really try much, and could have invested a bit more thinking into it.